# JSONObject removes decimal dot, if round number

Tags: json, rest, double, decimal

Using a rest service, we are transfering values using JSON.

At some point, we need to decide, wheter the incoming value was a long or a double. While

```
Double d = 17.0;

System.out.println("toString(): " + d.toString());
```

will result in

```
toString(): 17.0
```

the zero and the point gets removed, when wrapping the value inside a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("myDouble", d);
System.out.println(jo.toString());
```

Output:

```
{"myDouble":17}
```

The rest-Service has basically an EAV-Store, so it should not determine the type by the ValueNAME given. I testet 2 JSON-Implementations, both have the same behaviour.

can i somehow achieve, that the decimal value is appended in the JSONObject, without having to create my own implementation for it?

Comment: And you can't store d.toString() ? jo.put("myDouble", d.toString());

Comment: @gaepi: doh, youre right! :) this works for my purpose, but ofc. is just a workaround. (Then ofc. the object stored is not of Type Double, but a String, which can be bad, if you continue working with the json object or do some maths, etc.

Comment: Use a different JSON library (JSON Simple, Gson, Jackson). All the mentioned preserve at leave one decimal place of precision when serializing floating point numbers.

Comment: @Perception Perfect, `JSON Simple` does the trick. (tested activiti and primefaces JSONObject prior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos should go to Perception for the comment:

> Use a different JSON library (JSON Simple, Gson, Jackson). All the mentioned preserve at leave one decimal place of precision when serializing floating point numbers.

Used JSON Simple, which worked as expected.